# interpreting xsession-errors log after xrdp disconnection

Tags: d-bus, xubuntu, rdp

I am trying to understand why my xrdp drops immediately upon connection.
The `~/.xsession-errors` log showed this.

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified   
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

No protocol specified  
xrdb: Resource temporarily unavailable   
xrdb: Can't open display ':21.0'   
No protocol specified   
xhost:  unable to open display ":21.0"   
No protocol specified   
Error opening display!   
No protocol specified   
xhost:  unable to open display ":21.0"   
No protocol specified   
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus:  
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ipEErDtgMV: Connection refused   
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus:  
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ipEErDtgMV: Connection refused   
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus:  
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ipEErDtgMV: Connection refused   
No protocol specified   
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused    
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .   
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.
```

I was hoping it could give me some ideas about what is broken. After searching online for sometime, I haven't found a good way to do this. Could someone give me some help on this?

Comment: How do you launch xrdp ?

Comment: @MC68020  start remote desktop on windows